# Reverse Relationship in django 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have two models called car and producer. The two models have many to one relation between them.

```
class Producer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    producer = models.ForeignKey(Producer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name here
```

When i try to query the reverse relationship.

```
Producer.objects.filter(car__name='Mini')
```

then it return a queryset object

```
<QuerySet [<Producer: BMW>]>
```

when i try to assign the queryset object to a variable and fetch the name field result then it gives error.

```
obj1 = Producer.objects.filter(car__name='Mini')
    In [6]: obj1.name                                                                                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5155cb2773b4> in <module>
----> 1 obj1.name

AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'
```

what could be the reason for this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When do you use `get()` Django return an object and you can get the variables of that object, for example `obj1.name`, but when you use `filter`, Django return a `Queryset`, you have to iterate the queryset with a for:

```
mini_producers = Producer.objects.filter(car__name='Mini')

for producer in mini_producers:
    print(producer.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Queryset is a list of objects, not a single object.

So you can do:

```
obj1 = Producer.objects.filter(car__name='Mini').first(). # <- get first
In [6]: obj1.name
```

or in case you have to handle multiple.

```
for obj in obj1:
    print(obj.name)
    # do your logic
```